Effect of Pre-emphasis on Eye Diagram
Pre-emphasis is mainly used to boost high frequency component in the transmitted data. This is done by using FIR equalization. I am aware that, at the data transition, more current is pumped is pumped and it increases the amplitude (1 cycle for post tap) and the edge rate. This suggests that the eye width will be improved. I am confused like how is eye height improved if the data after one cycle (1st post tap) is getting de-emphasized (decreased amplitude)?

Here's a typical eye diagram for a system with no pre-emphasis:

(image source: Teledyne LeCroy)
You'll notice that the eye height (the height of the clear area in the middle with no traces running through it) is determined entirely by the small subset of the traces I circled in red.
The effect of pre-emphasis is to raise and lower the red traces to open the eye. If it also constricts the traces circled in yellow (lowers the upper traces and raises the lower traces) slightly that won't affect the eye opening.
